# DotCMIS and JSON Binding

Tags: cmis, dotcmis

I was looking at the Apache Chemistry dotCMIS project.

From some of the comments on the Apache web page and briefly looking at the source code, it doesn't look like it supports the new CMIS 1.1 JSON Binding.

Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now (August 2014), the Apache Chemistry DotCMIS codebase does not support the browser binding.

The good news is that there's a [community fork with browser binding support on github](https://github.com/OpenDataSpace/chemistry-dotcmis), so for now you should be able to [grab that](https://github.com/OpenDataSpace/chemistry-dotcmis) and use that version.

The authors of that code [are in discussions to contribute the code back to Apache](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/chemistry-dev/201408.mbox/%3C53E8DF76.9000800%40graudata.com%3E), so with any luck it'll be in the next official DotCMIS release in a month or two's time!

Comment: That sounds great.  I will check that out.